# The function 'ta.atr' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have been working on a strategy with Pinescript. The error that has been popping up is

> The function 'ta.atr' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.>

I have tried changing it but to no avail. Here is the code I have.

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI-Bollinger Bands-VFI Strategy", overlay=true)

// RSI Inputs
rsi_length = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=14, minval=1)
rsi_overbought = input.int(title="RSI Overbought", defval=70, minval=1)
rsi_oversold = input.int(title="RSI Oversold", defval=30, minval=1)

// Bollinger Bands Inputs
bb_length = input.int(title="BB Length", defval=20, minval=1)
bb_dev = input.float(title="BB Deviation", defval=2, minval=0.1)

// Volume Flow Indicator Inputs
vfi_length = input.int(title="VFI Length", defval=14, minval=1)

// ATR Inputs
atr_length = input.int(title="ATR Length", defval=14, minval=1)
atr_multiple = input.float(title="ATR Multiple", defval=2, minval=0.1)

// RSI Calculation
rsi_val = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)

// Bollinger Bands Calculation
[bb_upper, bb_middle, bb_lower] = ta.bb(close, bb_length, bb_dev)

// Volume Flow Indicator Calculation
vfi = math.sum(volume * (close - open) / (high - low), vfi_length) / math.sum(volume, vfi_length)

// Buy Signal
rsi_crossover = ta.crossover(rsi_val, rsi_oversold)
bb_crossunder = ta.crossunder(close, bb_lower)
vfi_crossover = ta.crossover(vfi, 0)

if (rsi_crossover and bb_crossunder and vfi_crossover)
    stop_loss = ta.atr(length) * atr_multiple
    take_profit = ta.atr(length) * atr_multiple
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
    strategy.exit("Exit Buy", "Buy", stop=close - stop_loss, limit=close + take_profit)

// Sell Signal
rsi_crossunder = ta.crossunder(rsi_val, rsi_overbought)
bb_crossover = ta.crossover(close, bb_upper)
vfi_crossunder = ta.crossunder(vfi, 0)

if (rsi_crossunder and bb_crossover and vfi_crossunder)
    stop_loss = ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
    take_profit = ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, comment="Sell")
    strategy.exit("Exit Sell", "Sell", stop=close + stop_loss, limit=close - take_profit)
```

The error appears on lines 36, 46 & 47.

I was working on a pinescript strategy using RSI, Bollinger Bands and Volume Flow Indicator. Then using ATR to set the take profit/ stop loss.

Answer (score 0):

When pinescript show you this recommandation, you should (if possible) move the calculation out of the local scope of your 'if' block.

The corrected code is here :

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI-Bollinger Bands-VFI Strategy", overlay=true)

// RSI Inputs
rsi_length = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=14, minval=1)
rsi_overbought = input.int(title="RSI Overbought", defval=70, minval=1)
rsi_oversold = input.int(title="RSI Oversold", defval=30, minval=1)

// Bollinger Bands Inputs
bb_length = input.int(title="BB Length", defval=20, minval=1)
bb_dev = input.float(title="BB Deviation", defval=2, minval=0.1)

// Volume Flow Indicator Inputs
vfi_length = input.int(title="VFI Length", defval=14, minval=1)

// ATR Inputs
atr_length = input.int(title="ATR Length", defval=14, minval=1)
atr_multiple = input.float(title="ATR Multiple", defval=2, minval=0.1)

// RSI Calculation
rsi_val = ta.rsi(close, rsi_length)

// Bollinger Bands Calculation
[bb_upper, bb_middle, bb_lower] = ta.bb(close, bb_length, bb_dev)

// Volume Flow Indicator Calculation
vfi = math.sum(volume * (close - open) / (high - low), vfi_length) / math.sum(volume, vfi_length)

// Buy Signal
rsi_crossover = ta.crossover(rsi_val, rsi_oversold)
bb_crossunder = ta.crossunder(close, bb_lower)
vfi_crossover = ta.crossover(vfi, 0)

stop_loss = ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
take_profit = ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
if (rsi_crossover and bb_crossunder and vfi_crossover)

    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
    strategy.exit("Exit Buy", "Buy", stop=close - stop_loss, limit=close + take_profit)

// Sell Signal
rsi_crossunder = ta.crossunder(rsi_val, rsi_overbought)
bb_crossover = ta.crossover(close, bb_upper)
vfi_crossunder = ta.crossunder(vfi, 0)

stop_loss := ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
take_profit := ta.atr(atr_length) * atr_multiple
if (rsi_crossunder and bb_crossover and vfi_crossunder)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, comment="Sell")
    strategy.exit("Exit Sell", "Sell", stop=close + stop_loss, limit=close - take_profit)
```